# Rich text box, SelectionChanged handler, and MVVM

Tags: silverlight-4.0, richtextbox, mvvm-light

SL 4 app.  We have a RichTextBox (from the Silverlight Toolkit) in a larger control.  When the selection in the textbox changes, we need to update some other controls based on the formatting of the selection.
The controls need to be updated from the ViewModel, so we send an MVVM Light message from the SelectionChanged handler to the appropriate ViewModel.

```
void RichTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
    if (null != rtb && rtb.Selection.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new UpdateTextFormatUiFromSelectedText() { Xaml = (sender as RichTextBox).Selection.Xaml.ToString()});
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, after sending the message the selection is lost and the cursor goes to the beginning of the text.  The routine that handles the UpdateTextFormatUiFromSelectedText message does not do anything to change the RTB.
Any insights in to what is going on would be appreciated...

Update:  If Messenger.Default.Send() is not called, the RTB behaves as expected.

Comment: Waht happens if you do this...   Messenger.Default.Send(new UpdateTextFormatUiFromSelectedText() { });